# Open different modal box depending on selected row in a gridview

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net, modal-dialog

I have a gridview that contain lot of rows, the rows can assume two different meaning. Depending to the meaning of row I need to open a different modal poupup, someone could explain me how to do that?

This is the code of gridview:

```
<asp:GridView ID="grd_elenco" runat="server" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal1">
```

this is how I create the modal-box:

```
<div id="#myModal1" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myLargeModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Titolo</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">

                         <!--my content-->

            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <asp:Button runat="server" type="button" Text="Chiudi" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

So, I need to change programmatically and depending of content of rows the data-target of gridview, is it possible?

Comment: you can do it with modal events http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-events

Comment: I read it, but I don't know where to start. Could you give me an input?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem with this code:

VB.NET

```
Private Sub grd_elenco_RowDataBound(sender As Object, e As GridViewRowEventArgs) Handles grd_elenco.RowDataBound
    Dim variable As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "column_name")) 'take the value from column
    e.Row.Attributes.Add("OnClick", "OpenModalBox(" + variable.ToString + ")")
End Sub
```

Javascript

```
function OpenModalBox(variable) {
    if (variable==0){
        $('#mymodal1').modal('show');
    } else {
        $('#mymodal2').modal('show');
    }
}
```